# Check list contains value in Twig template

Tags: java, html, templates, jtwig

I have this block of code:

```
<div>
    <dt class="question">Language</dt>
    <dd class="answer">
    {% if Wrapper.arrangements['signLanguage'] is defined %}
        Sign Language              
    {% else %}
        Not required
    {% endif %}
    </dd>
</div>
```

and then:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Wrapper {

    private List<String> arrangements;

}
```

Which always prints 'Not required' even when my Java Wrapper.arrangements object contains "signLanguage". Anyone spot what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your property is private, make it public or use a getter

Comment: Is this question about Twig (for PHP) or Jtwig (for Java)?

Comment: JTwig. And there are Getters provided through Lombok

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access Wrapper.arrangements in the same way you would a static function.  It is not static and is private so you will need to add the wrapper to your model presumably named "wrapper" and have a method named getArrangement that returns your arrangements list then in your template you will have the following:

```
{% if wrapper.getArrangements.contains('signLanguage') is defined %}
```